# Login and execute a query in sybase in a batch file

Tags: windows, cmd, sybase, sqlanywhere, login-script

I am trying to login in sybase and right away execute a query in my batch file. This is the line:

```
dbisql -c "uid=dba;pwd=sql" -q select max(id)
```

But it does not work, if i just do:

```
 dbisql -c "uid=dba;pwd=sql"
```

in the command line, it works and I can connect to the database but if I put the whole code it shows the following error:

```
Could not connect to the database. 
Database server not found 
SQLCODE : -100, OBDC 3 State = "08001" 

You are not connected to a database.
```

Can anyone help me, please?
Thank you, guys.

Comment: You say that `dbisql -c "uid=dba;pwd=sql"` works at the command line, and that `dbisql -c "uid=dba;pwd=sql" -q select max(id)` doesn't work from a batch file, but you haven't told us what happens if you try `dbisql -c "uid=dba;pwd=sql" -q select max(id)` on the command line. Until you've done so, we cannot determine if the issue you're having is the command or the batch file!

Comment: What OS (Windows? Unix? Linux?) are you on, if UNIX/Linux then what shell are you using, and what Sybase product (ASE? SQLAnywhere? IQ? Advantage?) are you trying to connect to?

Comment: Im using windows and SQL Anywhere

Comment: if i try `dbisql -c "uid=dba;pwd=sql" -q select max(id)` in the command line i get that error that i described in my question " Could not connect ... You are not connected to a database"

Comment: I get the same error executing it in the command line or  executing the batch file.

Comment: You haven't got a batch-file problem then, your issue is how to use your program from a command line interface. I have therefore removed your `batch-file` tag and replaced it with the `cmd`, `windows` and `sqlanywhere` tags to match your comments.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are doing wrong. But the following command works fine for me. The following command will give you the result in the command prompt.

```
dbisql -c "uid=dba;pwd=sql;eng=test" select 1
```